# center div slowly after hiding siblings jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I have long div containing images of some users on my website.
I can't seem to figure out how to slowly center a div after hiding its siblings.

http://jsfiddle.net/sXpT3/

My question is what to add my jQuery script for slowly centering the div clicked,
after hiding the others.

I tried to use animate, but that didn't seem to work if I do not position each div in absolute mode.

css

```
.users {
    width:100%;
    text-align:center;
    height: 100px;
    top:50%;
    margin-top:-100px;
    position:absolute;
}

.user {
    display:inline-block;
    *display:inline;
    width:90px;
    height:90px;
    margin:0 10px;
    border-radius:50px;
    border:5px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.9);
}
```

jQuery

```
$(function() {
    $('.user').click(function() {

        if ($(this).hasClass('active')) {
            $('.user').not(this).fadeIn(200);

            $(this).removeClass('active');
        } else {

            $('.user').not(this).fadeOut(200);

            $(this).addClass('active');
        }

    });
});
```

HTML

```
<div class="users">
    <div style="background:#0F9" class="user">
    </div>
    <div style="background:#0CF" class="user">
    </div>
    <div style="background:#F66" class="user">
    </div>
    <div style="background:#F09" class="user">
    </div>
    <div style="background:#FCF" class="user">
    </div>
    <div style="background:#996" class="user">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you mind if we change up the CSS or do you prefer that it stays as is?

Comment: Please feel free to do whatever you want.. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By only fading it out and not hiding it and then animating the hide, I can accomplish the effect you're looking for.
Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sXpT3/1/ 
JS:

```
$(function() {
    $('.user').click(function() {

        if ($(this).hasClass('active')) {
            $(this).removeClass('active');
            $('.user').not(this).show(200).fadeTo(200,1);
        } else {

            $(this).addClass('active');
            $('.user').not(this).fadeTo(200,0).hide(200);
        }

    });
});
```

Comment: This is just great! :) Thanks.. I have one thing though.. I notice that if I slow down the centering process, the chosen div "jumps" a little at the end of the centering process. Is there a way to prevent that?

Comment: This is a good solution, but it has the unfortunate effect of still being constricted to the `inline-block` so any items on other rows will slide left or right before moving up a row as needed. To solve that though you'll need more extensive JS and style changes to get a nice direct 'point a to point b' animation.

Comment: @DigTheDoug In this case, it doesn't matter, since I have a div for additional content placed outside of the parent div.